# Issue with Xamarin.iOS Native Binding - CocoaTouch Framework

Tags: ios, visual-studio, cocoa-touch, xamarin.ios, swift4.2

I have created a [CocoaTouch Framework](https://github.com/sahil-khanna/CocoaTouch-Framework) using Swift and want to import it in a [Xamarin.iOS app](https://github.com/sahil-khanna/Xamarin-Native-Binding). Below are the steps I followed with reference to [this blog](https://medium.com/@Flash3001/binding-swift-libraries-xamarin-ios-ff32adbc7c76)

1) Generated APIDefinations using the below command

```
sharpie bind -sdk iphoneos12.1 /MyFirstFramework.framework/Headers/MyFirstFramework-Swift.h
```

2) Added Native reference

[image]

3) Added the below Swift 4 packages in the Xamarin.iOS app (that consumes the framework)
[image]

When I build and run the app on device or simulator, it crashes. The crash logs are as below

```
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Termination Description: DYLD, Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftos.dylib | Referenced from: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/27F3E785-3CE9-4293-9045-A0E643163F6A/SHApp.app/Frameworks/libswiftMetal.dylib | Reason: image not found
```

I then, in Xcode Framework project, set `Always Embed Swift Standard Libraries = Yes` and included the framework in Xamarin. After this, the Xamarin.iOS app doesn't crash, but does not perform any action on invoking the Framework methods

```
SHLib.MyFirstFramework.Launch();
Console.Write(SHLib.MyFirstFramework.Print);
```

I need help in understanding the things that I may be doing wrong for [Xamarin.iOS app](https://github.com/sahil-khanna/Xamarin-Native-Binding).

---

**Edit 1**

I have added the missing package libswiftos and not the app doesn't crash. The issue now is that when executing the code, the framework returns null for the `Print` property, whereas it is supposed to return the hardcoded text `"Returned by MyFirstFramework"`

***Swift code in MyFirstFramework.framework***
[image: Swift code in MyFirstFramework.framework]

***Result in Visual Studio***
[image: Result in Visual Studio]

Comment: Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftos.dylib   It seems that you didn't add the nuget package Xamarin.Swift4.OS.  You can add it from nuget.

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT: Thanks for pointing that out. I have added the missing package. However, the native framework is not executing as expected. Please refer to "Edit 1" section of the question